# How to echo what people are typing into a search box

Tags: javascript, html, web-development-server

I have a javascript search function with a box where people can search my products. Is there anyway I can send their word search to an e-mail account of mine, so I can gather what people are searching for e-commerce research? I am not looking to capture e-mail addresses or anything, just merely to echo what they are putting in. Here is a snippet of my code:

```js
function openPage() {
  var x = document.getElementById("search").value;

  if (x.toLowerCase() === "Wave".toLowerCase()) {
    window.top.location = ("/Products#!/products/wave-usb---dealer-only---click-for-more-info");
  }

  if (x.toLowerCase() === "Wave USB".toLowerCase()) {
    window.top.location = ("/Products#!/products/wave-usb---dealer-only---click-for-more-info");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="search" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="Search here..." id="search" onchange="openPage()">
```

Comment: what platform are you using? if you don't use a platform how do you code the e commerce? node js for back end?

Comment: splicing saas, a hosted package from Denmark where you edit in a browser but can also drop in your own code

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
let tId;
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("input", function() {
  clearTimeout(tId);
  tId = setTimeout(function() { // debounce so only send when user pauses
    var x = document.getElementById("search").value.toLowerCase();
    fetch('/saveSearch?search='+encodeURIComponent(x))
    if (x=== "wave") {
      window.top.location = ("/Products#!/products/wave---dealer-only---click-for-more-info");
    }
    else  if (x === "wave usb") {
      window.top.location = ("/Products#!/products/wave-usb---dealer-only---click-for-more-info");
    }
  }, 500)
})
```

```html
<input type="search" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="Search here..." id="search">
```

Comment: this solution will send request to the back end with every input. and if he wants to send it as an email maybe it will be better to create a "search" button, and add a click event listener . on click send request to the back end and the back end can store it on db or only send the email with the search query

Comment: No it won't. I added a debounce so when the user stops for half a second it will send

Comment: where would I put the e-mail address for it to echo to that?

Comment: In the savesearch server process

Comment: excellent thank you, so I just replace +encodeURIComponent with an e-mail address?

Comment: No. You write a server process called saveSearch and in that one you send an email to your email address. `encodeURIComponent(x)` is what the user typed